# python Non greedy regular expression searching too many data

Tags: regex, python-2.7, regex-greedy, non-greedy

String: `'<td attr="0">str1</td><td attr="5">str2</td><td attr="7">str2</td><td attr="9">str4</td>'`

I want to search and get only **first "td" tag which contains text: "str2"**. so I tried two different non greedy expressions as below:

```
>>> mystring = '<td attr="0">str1</td><td attr="5">str2</td><td attr="7">str2</td><td attr="9">str4</td>'
>>> print re.search("(<td.*?str2.*?</td>)",mystring).group(1)
<td attr="0">str1</td><td attr="5">str2</td>
>>> print re.search(".*(<td.*?str2.*?</td>).*",mystring).group(1)
<td attr="7">str2</td>
```

Here I was expecting output as `"<td attr="5">str2</td>"`, because I have used non greedy expression in regular expression. What is wrong here and how to fetch the expected search result?

Note: I can not use html parser because my actual data-set is not so much formatted for xml parsing

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Use `[^>]` instead of `.`:

```
>>> print re.search("(<td[^>]*?>str2.*?</td>)",mystring).group(1)
<td attr="5">str2</td>
```

([see demo](https://regex101.com/r/VSPPFa/1))

Or, **better**, use [HTMLParser](https://docs.python.org/2/library/htmlparser.html).

EDIT: This regex will match even sub-tags:

```
(<td[^<]*?(?:<(?!td)[^<]*?)*str2.*?</td>)
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have not used html parser because my actual data set is not in proper xml format and parser fails. Also in <td> tag, there is a chance to have multiple other child tags like <tr>. But the main point is I want to fetch first "td" tag which contains text: "str2".

Comment: I understand. I think [this](https://regex101.com/r/VSPPFa/3) will work even with sub-tags.